# Do contact picker queries require the read_contacts permission depending on the android version?

Tags: android, android-intent

We have been experimenting with the Android contact picker to allow users to select a contact without the app requiring the READ_CONTACTS permission. The following intents appear to work on 4.0 (ICS) devices as well as a 2.3.3 emulator:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACION_GET_CONTENT);
contactPickerIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); // returns content://com.android.contacts/data/...

Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI); // returns content://com.android.contacts/lookup/...
```

On a 2.2 emulator and certain pre-ICS models (e.g., HTC Thunderbolt, Motorola Droid), however, attempting to query the returned UI results in a permission denial exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r1-52345052324E483C32/1 from pid=273, uid=10036 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

This looks like a OS or device fragmentation issue; we're seeking clarification on this topic so that we can move forward with this or an alternate approach.

Thoughts?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. In my ICS phone, I don't need the permission and in my 1.6 G1 I do. If the fragmentation cannot be pinpointed, I would be satisfied in knowing how I can check if the call will go through without a SecurityException on this device.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602641/how-can-i-check-if-startactivity-will-fail-with-securityexception-due-to-lack

Comment: You do not need `READ_CONTACTS` for the Android 2.2 emulator for `ACTION_PICK`, as this sample app illustrates: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ConfigChange/Bundle

Comment: Just tested on a 2.2 Evo Shift 4G: Got exception. No exception on Evo View 4G 2.3.3